# I need to do two columns web scraption with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

```
<div class="content">
<div class="container">
<div class="row pt-2">
<div class="col pe-1">
<div class="grid-cell p-2">
<a href="united-states_florida/company/met-west-commercial-lender/tom-mchugh-975">
              Tom Mchugh
            </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col ps-1">
<div class="grid-cell p-2">
            Company:
            <span>
<a href="united-states_florida/company/met-west-commercial-lender">
                Met West Commercial Lender
                  </a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My result showing like this

[image]

I want to look like following table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Tom Mchugh | Met West Commercial Lender |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be different approaches. Here is an elegant one.

```
y = df.Name.values
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : y[::2], 'B' : y[1::2]})
```

Comment: Thanks you! That's my need it, very useful and clearly solution.